# Citrix Xenserver vs xen 4.1 hypervisor vs xen XCP etc?

Tags: xenserver

I'm needing to use XEN for a project that contains multiple GPU cards with PCI passthrough.

However, I'm not really sure which version of XEN I should be using.  In all likelyhood I may need to tweak the source code to get the GPU's to work properly.

Initially I installed Ubuntu server and started following this link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xen

But then I realised that there are also bare metal installations of zen and a cloud version.

There are versions available on the citrix site as well as xen.org.
I'm wanting to use the free open source version.  What are the differences between them all and which should I be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I should have read the wikipedia article.  It looks like they are all based on the xen hypervisor.  The different products are simply built around the hypervisor.  So the ubuntu article still applies somewhat, although the latest hypervisor is 4.1.1

Answer (score 0):

The new XenServer supports GPU passthrough, it's called "XenServer Boston"  I haven't tried this new beta release, however I am quite happy with previous versions!

http://blogs.citrix.com/2011/05/18/xenserver-boston-beta-program/

Regards,

Port Forward Podcast

Answer (score 0):

GPU passthrough using PCI forwarding works for me under Xen Server 5. I've tested it under a system with 2 physical GPUs which are attached to 2 CentOS 5.4 VMs.